# Request Accept media type in RESTlet 2

Tags: header, get, request, restlet-2.0, media-type

How can I identify the resource media type in RESTlet2, I tried following in my class extended from ServerResource

```
 @Get
 public Object onGET(){
  System.out.println("=================");
  System.out.println(this.getRequestEntity().getMediaType());
...
```

It prints a null when I do any request. I want to get the list of all Accept media types in header.

Answer (score 4):

Well seems like I figured it out:

```
Request.getCurrent().getClientInfo().getAcceptedMediaTypes();
```

Returns list of all accepted media types.